# Div positioning broken by input

Tags: html, css, input

I'm having a problem achieving the layout for a website I'm designing.

There are three blue divs across the top of the page under which I have placed four red divs. Each of the red divs will take up just less than a quarter of the width of the page.

After putting an input field in the right most blue div the position of the red divs gets shifted to the right and some red divs appear below others.

I've tried changing the position properties on various divs but can't seem to restore the layout I wanted and have tried adding margins but to no avail.

Can anyone see the problem in my code and/or layout? Any help will be greatly appreciated, I've included all the code in a JSfiddle page.

Many thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cb5za9y/

```
enter code here<style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: So all those four red divs should all be at the left side of the page, under the first blue div?

Comment: Apologies, I'll bear this in mind in future, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was simply a `</div>` missing after your input, which broke the layout. [Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cb5za9y/1/).

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! Thank you for spotting that!